# Twitter bootstrap modal from HTML as dialog?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to display a twitter bootstrap modal dialog as per the first example, the statis dialog.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

However, I want it to show in the state where it is as a modal dialog (blacked out scnks.reen)

It doesn't seem to do this by default, and I haven't been able to figure out what attributes or classes to include to do it?

Thanks

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>` to the page show/hide it with modal dialog